# EMV Interaction between Transaction Type Cash, AUC and Additional Terminal Capabilities

Tags: payment, credit-card, emv

The app I'm working on takes cards and a client is saying some of their cards are being declined and I have to figure out why its declined.
I'm by no means an expert on EMV so any help would be appreciated.

The card in question is a VISA card with an AUC of

```
    Tag 9F 07: Application Usage Control [VCPS] : FF 00
    Byte 1 bit 8 = 1      Valid for domestic (manual) cash transactions
        bit 7 = 1      Valid for international (manual) cash transactions
        bit 6 = 1      Not used for VCPS
        bit 5 = 1      Not used for VCPS
        bit 4 = 1      Not used for VCPS
        bit 3 = 1      Not used for VCPS
        bit 2 = 1      Valid at ATMs
        bit 1 = 1      RFU
    Byte 2 bit 8 = 0      Domestic cashback NOT allowed
        bit 7 = 0      International cashback NOT allowed
        bit 6 = 0      RFU
        bit 5 = 0      RFU
        bit 4 = 0      RFU
        bit 3 = 0      RFU
        bit 2 = 0      RFU
        bit 1 = 0      RFU
```

I can't find a formal definition of what a Cash transaction is in the EMV books.
Am I to understand a transaction type of Cash means the merchant would give Cash to the Cardholder?

The Additional Terminal Capabilities are 600080C000.

```
b8 b7 b6 b5 b4 b3 b2 b1 Meaning
1  x  x  x  x  x  x  x Cash
x  1  x  x  x  x  x  x Goods
x  x  1  x  x  x  x  x Services
x  x  x  1  x  x  x  x Cashback
x  x  x  x  1  x  x  x Inquiry 20
x  x  x  x  x  1  x  x Transfer 21
x  x  x  x  x  x  1  x Payment 22
x  x  x  x  x  x  x  1 Administrative
Table 28: Add’l Term. Capabilities Byte 1 - Transaction Type Capability
```

The first byte is `60` so the terminal can only perform Goods and Services transactions.

So am I correct in saying that since the cards AUC only specifies Cash and the terminal doesn't do cash, then the Card should be declined?

Thanks

EDIT: More Info

What's even more confusing

```
1st GEN is performed
Response is ARQC
then there is no 2nd GEN
```

And then the terminal shows a Decline message (Datecs BluPad500). 
We don't even get the callback from the library to perform the online request.

PasteBin of the card logs: REMOVED

I'm trying to figure this out myself or at least have a better idea of what to ask before I go to Datecs support.

Comment: Where does the transaction decline? Is it declined offline without sending to host? Or is the host declining the online transaction or is the card declining after receiving the online response from host.

Comment: @Adarsh Question updated, with some more info

Comment: So it means the terminal has not declined the transaction. The decision was to go online. Now was the transaction sent online? Unless you have the sufficient data, all are guesses

Comment: Saw the logs now, the card is waiting for issuer authentication. Either there was no response from host, or the received host response was not sent to the card

Comment: There's a callback in the Datecs Library for when we're supposed to send the online request. but its never called, so it sounds like library is acting incorrectly and I need to talk to Datecs.

Comment: @triggs Please redact ICC Public Key Certificate as well as card number 4027******9383 is there as well.

Comment: @triggs Regarding your logs, nothing is wrong with this transaction from the technical point of view. AUC indicates support for goods and services as well - it's just BTT that didn't print it. If you had issue with AUC, you would have more bits set in the TVR byte 2 and you only have different app versions, which is quite normal and safe. 

What I would look around is the amount that is Swiss Franc in Ireland, so it's probably DCC and, however it may be a coincidence, it looks too round. Please check that currency conversion is handled correctly - maybe this causes the transaction to fail

Comment: @michalGluchowski, thanks, I'll take a look at the country code - transaction currency and see if that changes any thing